# ¿Cómo llama a un método desde otra class?

Tags: java, método

Hola disculpen tengo un problema en mi estudio de Java ¿cómo llamar un método desde otro `class`?
Ejemplo:

```
public class metodos {
   public static void mensaje(){
      System.out.println(" hola mundo ");
  }
}
```

Ejemplo:

Tengo este Método `static` y de valor de retorno `void` lo cual no se necesita crear un objeto de esta  `class` para llamar este método ¿cómo podría llamarlo? ¿Con `extends` o cómo?

Comment: System.out.println es un ejemplo de como se realiza, en esta caso `System` es una clase que tiene un campo estático llamado `out` el cual tiene  un método `println`

Answer (score 9):

En java es importante escribir correctamente los modificadores, en este caso `Public` debe ser escrito con minúscula `public`.

Te recomiendo este articulo: [public, private y protected Java.Tipos de modificadores de acceso.](http://aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=665:public-private-y-protected-javatipos-de-modificadores-de-acceso-visibilidad-en-clases-subclases-cu00693b&catid=68:curso-aprender-programacion-java-desde-cero&Itemid=188)

---

Es importante escribir correctamente tu código ya que de otra forma tendrás problemas al tratar de compilar. Por cierto los nombres de clases por convención se escriben al inicio con mayúsculas (ver [sintaxis básica](http://codehero.co/java-desde-cero-sintaxis-basica/)).

```
class Metodos{
public void mensaje() (
   System.out.println("hola mundo");
   )
)
```

---

Para llamar el método mensaje() de esta clase

```
public class Metodos{
public void mensaje() (
   System.out.println("hola mundo");
   )
)
```

**si es que no estuviera definido como estatico**, de la clase anterior desde una clase simplemente lo realizas de esta forma, instancias la clase, y mandas llamar el método, es importante que este definido como `public` para ser llamado desde otra clase (ver [modificadores de acceso](http://aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=665:public-private-y-protected-javatipos-de-modificadores-de-acceso-visibilidad-en-clases-subclases-cu00693b&catid=68:curso-aprender-programacion-java-desde-cero&Itemid=188)):

```
//Instancias la clase.
Metodos myClase = new Metodos();
//ejecutas el metodo de la clase.
myClase.mensaje();
```

Un ejemplo llamandolo desde la clase principal

```
class ClasePrincipal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Instancias la clase.
        Metodos myClase = new Metodos();
        //ejecutas el metodo de la clase.
        myClase.mensaje();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Metodos{
public static void mensaje() (
   System.out.println("hola mundo");
   )
)
```

Para llamar el método mensaje() **el cual esta definido como estatico**, simplemente:

```
Metodos.mensaje();
```

Un ejemplo llamandolo desde la clase principal

```
class ClasePrincipal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //ejecutas el metodo de la clase.
        myClase.mensaje();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
nombreDeLaClase.nombreDelMetodo();
```

Desde otras clases siempre y cuando el método sea público.

Comment: Nombre de la clase y luego el método siempre y cuando sea un método estático. Si no. Debes instanciar la clase antes y luego llamar al método.

Comment: Si. El preguntaba por un metodo estatico.f

Answer (score 2):

Creamos un objeto de dicha clase de la siguiente forma

```
Metodos nombreObjeto = new Metodos();
```

Luego utilizamos el objeto para llamar los métodos (en este caso los públicos) de dicha clase.

```
nombreObjeto.mensaje();
```

Comment: Esto no es correcto. El método es estático.

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tenemos estas 2 clases.

Primeramente "Operación1":

```
public class Operacion1{
    public static int sumar(int a, int b){
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Y después "Operación2":

```
public class Operacion2{
    public int sumar(int a, int b){
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Vamos a hacer un método main y se verá más sencillo:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){


        System.out.println(Operacion1.sumar(5,7)); // Imprimirá 12

        // Ejemplo con Operación2
        Operacion2 operacion = new Operacion2();
        System.out.println(Operacion2.sumar(5,7)); // Imprimirá 12
    }
}
```

Si el método es estático, entonces lo llamamos con en el primer ejemplo `NombreDeLaClase.metodo()`, y sino, tendremos que instanciar la clase (estaremos creando un objeto) y luego a la variable operación llamamos al método sumar. La forma de hacerlo es `nombreDeLaVariable.metodo()`.

Comment: Debe ser System.out.println(operacion.sumar(5,7)); no usar Operacion2