# Como llamar desde una actividad a un método de otra clase

Tags: java, android

Os presento mi problema:

Tengo una **actividad** 
llamada `public class PosicionamientoActivity extends AppCompatActivity` ,

y una **clase java**  (no una actividad)

```
public class DecisorCoordenadas {
   public DecisorCoordenadas(Context contexto, Coordinador coordinador) {
```

Me gustaría saber como podría ejecutar un **método** ( `public void resetInfo_Coordenadas(){`) de mi clase java desde la actividad.

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar algo de tu código para meternos en contexto?

Comment: Creando una instancia o sino intenta con un método estático.. suerte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para llamar un método de otra clase en una `Activity`, primeramente el método debe estar definido con el modificador `public`, lo cual es correcto:

```
public class DecisorCoordenadas {
   public DecisorCoordenadas(Context contexto, Coordinador coordinador) {
   ...
   ...
```

Si revisamos los parámetros que necesita, son el `Contexto` de la `Activity`, aunque puede ser usado el de la aplicación lo cual es más ligero (Revisa como se usaría ya que en algunos casos requieres el de la `Activity` por ejemplo al crear un diálogo dentro de la clase), y un objeto de tipo `Coordinador`

Como el método `DecisorCoordenadas()` no esta definido como `static` se tiene que instanciar la clase para llamar al método desde la `Activity`.

**En el caso del método descrito en tu pregunta, en realidad este método es el [constructor](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.mx/2012/07/normal-0-21-false-false-false_103.html) que sirve para inicializar la clase**:

```
DecisorCoordenadas decisorCoordenadas = new DecisorCoordenadas(this, myObjetoCoordinador);
```

o

```
DecisorCoordenadas decisorCoordenadas = new DecisorCoordenadas(getApplicactionContext(), myObjetoCoordinador);
```

---

> Me gustaría saber como podría ejecutar un método

```
public void resetInfo_Coordenadas(){
```

> de mi clase java desde la actividad.

Imagino este método se encuentra dentro de la clase `DecisorCoordenadas`, entonces se puede llamar de esta forma desde la `Activity`, primeramente instanciamos la clase ya que el método no esta definido como `static` y al tener la instancia podemos llamar el método:

```
DecisorCoordenadas decisorCoordenadas = new DecisorCoordenadas(this, myObjetoCoordinador);
decisorCoordenadas.resetInfo_Coordenadas();
```

---

Una pregunta un poco similar esta **[realizada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26445/95)** en el Tag Java en el caso de Android seria similar.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que crear un objeto de la clase DecisorCoordenadas haciendo un

```
DecisorCoordenadas dc = new DecisorCoordenadas(this, myCoordinador);
```

Y luego ya puedes llamar al método usando el objeto antes creado.

```
dc.resetInfo_Coordenadas();
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a instanciar la clase desde tu `Activity` de esta forma:

```
DecisorCoordenadas dc = new DecisorCoordenadas(this, coordinador);
dc.resetInfo_Coordenadas();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una instancia de tu clase o hacer tu método estático:

```
public static void resetInfo_Coordenadas(){ ... }
```

En tu clase principal accederías con el nombre de tu clase (punto) y el nombre del método:

```
DecisorCoordenadas.resetInfo_Coordenadas();
```